# How to render html element in pre / REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am working on a blog post creation tool and I need a engine when I write in textarea `<hr/>` I get a line, or when I write `<img/>` I get an image but it doesn't render.

The post is written in a textarea and should be displayed in a div.

How to do it?

```
const PostCreate = () => {
    const [postValue, changeValue] = useState('')
    const handleChangeValue = (e:any) => {
        changeValue(e.target.value)
        console.log(postValue);
    }
    return (
        <div className='postCreate'>
            Create New Post
            <textarea onChange={handleChangeValue} value={postValue}/>
            <div>
                {postValue}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If I write `<hr/>` I get the string `<hr/>` instead of a line:
[image: error img]

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you want to write HTML markup in the text area? If so, you need to use [special React API](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render it as HTML and not text.

Comment: It's mentioned in the docs on dangerouslySetInnerHtml as well but I still want to emphasise on the risk for XSS attacks when doing this. *PLEASE* be sure to sanitize your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop for the `div`.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postValue }} />
```

You can check it on [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) document.